# Py2Exe local server does not execute CGI

Tags: python, cgi, py2exe

I have a certain Python program that relies on a CGI script, which works when I launch a Python BaseHTTPServer with a CGIHTTPServer. But I would like all this to be run without installing Python, so I used Py2Exe.

I manage to create a .exe from my script, which indeed creates a working local web server when executed. CGI scripts, however, are just shown as code and not executed.

Here's the whole server script, which also launches the default browser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import webbrowser
import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer

server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 8008)
handler.cgi_directories = ["/cgi"]
httpd = server(server_address, handler)
webbrowser.open_new("http://localhost:8008/cgi/script.py");
httpd.serve_forever()
```

However, that script.py is just shown and not executed. I can't figure out why, and I have tried a few different versions in handler.cgi_directories, just in case...

Comment: You are starting the browser before you start the server

Comment: Hehe, no, that's not the answer, but thanks. That script works when called by Python - the browser takes a while to initialize, so httpd is already serving by then. If I start the browser after 'serving forever' that line is never called, though. 

Anyway, once the server is up and running, I may open a browser window manually and browse to that address, with the same results: I see the CGI code, it's not being executed.

Comment: run tcpdump on the lo inerface and see the requests and responses.

Comment: I guess I can do that with Firebug too, right? But I'm not sure what's your point. What am I looking for? CGI scripts are not executed - it's a server issue, right? Similar to .htaccess not being properly configured in Apache. 

I suspect, however, that it is related to how Python interprets CGI. Maybe it calls itself (Python), which wouldn't work within a .exe because... well, there's no Python to be found.

Comment: I think its more likely a webroot path issue.  If it were python you would get an error, not the file.

Answer (score 1):

problem is py2exe only converts your server script to exe, all cgi scripts are still .py and they require python installation to run. try converting each and every script in `'cgi'` directory.
Assuiming you have `server.py` in root dir and cgi scripts at `wwwroot\cgi-bin` your `setup.py` should look like

```
#!usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, os

setup(name='server',
    console=['server.py'],
    options={
                "py2exe":{
                        "unbuffered": True,
                        "packages": "cgi, glob, re, json, cgitb",       # list all packages used by cgi scripts
                        "optimize": 2,
                        "bundle_files": 1
                }},
    zipfile="library.zip")
os.rename("dist\\library.zip","dist\\library.zip.bak")                  # create backup of the library file

files=[]
for f in os.listdir("wwwroot\\cgi-bin"):                                # list all cgi files with relative path name
    files.append("wwwroot\\cgi-bin\\"+f)

setup(name='cgi',
    console= files,
    options={
        "py2exe":{
                        "dist_dir": "dist\\wwwroot\\cgi-bin",
                        "excludes": "cgi, glob, re, json, cgitb",       # we are going to discard this lib, may as well reduce work
                        "bundle_files": 1
                }
            },
    zipfile="..\\..\\library.zip")                                      # make sure zipfile points to same file in both cases

os.remove("dist\\library.zip")                                          # we don't need this generated library
os.rename("dist\\library.zip.bak","dist\\library.zip")                  # we have already included everything in first pass
```